# Updated version warning in android studio for dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I am working on a project where I have made another gradle file which holds all version and dependency details. Now when I am mentioning that to my module level I am not getting a warning or error for "newer version available".

This is the sample code I am using:

```
ext {
    gson_version = '2.8.0'
}

...

implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gson_version"
```

For this I am not getting any warning that a newer version is available.

But if I replace the last line with

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

then I am able to see a warning that a newer version is available.

Is there any way we can have the same lint warning on last statement of dependency without any plugin?